# How to replace "a" with "d", "b" with "e", "c" with "f", . . . "x" with "a", "y" with "b", and "z" with "c"?

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I would like to perform this search and replacement on a string, say `password`.

As you can understand from the question, after replacement the string should become `sdvvzrug`.

But unfortunately the following code outputs `bbbbcaab`:

```
$search = range("a", "z");
$replace = array_merge(range("d", "z"), range("a", "c"));
echo str_replace($search, $replace, "password");
```

What may be causing the issue here? At first I suspected the use of arrays in `str_replace`, therefore I used a loop and tried replacing one character at a time:

```
$search = range("a", "z");
$replace = array_merge(range("d", "z"), range("a", "c"));
$str = "password";
    for($i = 0; $i < 26; $i++)
    {
    $str = str_replace($search[$i], $replace[$i], $str);
    }
echo $str;
```

To my utter dismay, the result remained the same. What am I doing wrong and how should I achieve the correct results?

Comment: See a correct implementation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php#107475 `str_rot('password', 3);`

Comment: If you still prefer to do character replace, try using strtr instead of str_replace.

Comment: This is usually called a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other answers have explained how you can do this, so I will focus on the "What am I doing wrong?" part.

So, your `for`-loop is equivalent to this:

```
$str = str_replace('a', 'd', $str);
$str = str_replace('b', 'e', $str);
$str = str_replace('c', 'f', $str);
$str = str_replace('d', 'g', $str);
$str = str_replace('e', 'h', $str);
$str = str_replace('f', 'i', $str);
$str = str_replace('g', 'j', $str);
// ...
$str = str_replace('z', 'c', $str);
```

As you can see, this sort of "sweeps through" the alphabet: `a` gets replaced with `d`, and later `d` gets replaced `g`, and later `g` gets replaced with `j`. The problem is that when you're replacing `d` with `g`, you're doing it regardless of whether the `d` represents what was originally a `d` or what was originally an `a`. Each `str_replace` is discarding information; after the first line, you can't tell whether the string `ddd` was originally `add`, or originally `dad`, and when you change `d` to `g`, you get `ggg` instead of `dgg` or `gdg` or whatnot.

The reason the version with just a single `str_replace` had the same result is that `str_replace` does the same thing as your loop: it just iterates over the search-array, performing the replacements, and doesn't ensure that it never "re-replaces" a substring. That's why you need to use a method such as `strtr` that's specifically designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

Doing this multi-pass replacement is wrong. Using strtr will resolve the problem, because it won't change **already replaced** characters.

This is how you got bbbbcaab:

```
    :password
a->d:pdssword
b->e:pdssword
c->f:*
d->g:pgssworg
e->h:*
f->i:*
g->j:pjssworj
h->k:*
i->l:*
j->m:pmssworm
k->n:*
l->o:*
m->p:ppssworp
n->q:*
o->r:ppsswrrp
p->s:sssswrrs
q->t:*
r->u:sssswuus
s->v:vvvvwuuv
t->w:*
u->x:vvvvwxxv
v->y:yyyywxxy
w->z:yyyyzxxy
x->a:yyyyzaay
y->b:bbbbzaab
z->c:bbbbcaab
```

Answer (score 1):

Here we go,

```
$search = range("a", "z");
$replace = array_merge(range("d", "z"), range("a", "c"));
$str = "password";
$newstr = '';
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++)
{
    $key = array_search($str[$i],$search);
    $newstr .= $replace[$key]; 
}    
echo $newstr;
```

**[DEMO.](http://codepad.org/8VJ78Keq)**

Answer (score 1):

[`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) does all the replacements sequentially, regardless of whether the string is a derived value or a new one. Use [`strtr`](http://php.net/strtr) instead to do all the replacements in one go:

From the [documentation for `str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace):

> **Replacement order gotcha**
>
> Because str_replace() replaces left to right, it might replace a previously inserted value when doing multiple replacements.

I made some modifications to your `for` loop to help you understand how you got that output:

```
<?php

$str = "password";
$search = range("a", "z");
$replace = array_merge(range("d", "z"), range("a", "c"));

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

for($i = 0; $i < 26; $i++)
{
    $beforeStr = $str;
    $str = str_replace($search[$i], $replace[$i], $str);

    //var_dump($search[$i], $replace[$i], $str);

    if ($beforeStr !== $str) {
        echo "$i) $search[$i] -> $replace[$i]\n";
        echo "Replacement: $before -> $str";
    } else {
        echo "$i) $search[$i] -> $replace[$i]\n";
        echo "Replacement: none";
    }
    echo "\n\n";
}

echo $str;
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/91476)

The solution would be to use `strtr`. Here's how:

```
$replacePairs = array_combine($search, $replace);
echo strtr('password', $replacePairs); // => sdvvzrug
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/91450)

---

**Note:**  **Don't try to roll out your own encryption algorithm or protocol;**  that is extremely error-prone. Use a library that is tried and tested. See [this security.SE post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own) for why you shouldn't roll out your own encryption algorithms.